# Is viewsets and routers absolutely necessary (specifically in the case of nested serializers)?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to extend my accounts table with the help of serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer.
While doing so, I am trying to create my custom views. But while passing the data in postman to register the users, I encounter the following error.

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /accounts/register/
Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "account-detail".
You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

My serializers looks as:

```
class AccountProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.CharField(source='get_absolute_url', read_only=True)

    # id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model=AccountProfile
        fields = ['is_operation_manager', 'is_godown_manager', 'is_accountant', 'user_id']

        read_only_fields = ['user']




class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    profile = AccountProfileSerializer()

    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type':'password'}, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['url', 'email', 'password', 'password2', 'phone_number', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'profile']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password' : {'write_only': True},
            #'users': {'lookup_field': 'user'}

        }

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        password = self.validated_data['password']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']

        if (password != password2):
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'Password Error' : 'Passwords do not match. Please try again'})

        check = validated_data.pop('password2')
        db_password = validated_data.pop('password')

        account = Account(**validated_data)
        account.set_password(db_password)
        account.save()

        # return profile_data
        AccountProfile.objects.create(user=account, **profile_data)
        return account
```

And my view looks as:

```
class UserRegistration(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    @transaction.atomic
    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})

            if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I have also tried naming the url to account detail as:

```
    path('register/', views.UserRegistration.as_view(), name="account-detail"),
```

But I keep on getting the same error. Everywhere I have searched I found hyperlinkedModelSerializers being used with viewsets and routers only. Is that the mistake here? I am sure there are some options.

Also the registration form does not appear in the web-browser view? What might be causing this? (Any information would be highly valuable)

Answer (score 0):

> Is viewsets and routers absolutely necessary (specifically in the case of nested serializers)?

Absolutely not

> I have also tried naming the url to account detail as:

The issue here being that you have an url that doesn't include the pk - which the router do for free.
Your urls.py should look like:

```
re_path('register/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/', views.UserRegistration.as_view(), name="account-detail"),
```

Comment: Wouldn't this affect the basic functionality? This url is for registering a new user so by default there is no primary key associated with it.
Is creating a new url instead a better idea? Or will it not work?

Is the lookup_field required in this case?

Comment: Then how would the url point to the user - which is what the hyperlinkedserializer tries to do ?

Comment: yes exactly. I am trying to do all of that in the create() method. Where the new user while registering will be related to their profile. And after the user is created, it's id is then associated with the profile where the hyperlinkedserializer is supposed to have pointed

Comment: Does   adding  profile = AccountProfileSerializer()  to the end makes any difference?
What I am trying to say is? Is there a way for me to automate the process during registration else it would be a repetitive process right?
<br>
I may be wrong in my assumption. Please suggest me some resources to help me brush up my skills in this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the initial problem. It was required for me to include the HyperlinkedIdentityField to relate by using id. Simply doing this removed the issues.

```
profile_detail = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
                            view_name="account-detail", 
                            lookup_field = 'id')
```

and then adding profile_detail to fields, simply solved the problem.

However now when I try to create a user another error saying IntegrityError comes up. Saying,

```
IntegrityError at /accounts/register/user/
(1062, "Duplicate entry '8' for key 'user_id'")
```

This has previously been answered in stack overflow but right now I can't seem to get my head around it.